# Converting (not printing) a one-page-per-sheet PDF into multi-page-per-sheet PDF in DotNet

Tags: .net, pdf

I need to convert (not print) a PDF with multiple individual pages into a PDF with 4 pages per sheet, so every page in the target PDF contains 4 pages from the source PDF. It would be best if I could use a DotNET library for this.

I've tested [Spire PDF](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Introduce/pdf-for-net-introduce.html), which has an example how to take a source PDF and [print it with multiple pages per sheet](https://www.e-iceblue.com/Tutorials/Spire.PDF/Spire.PDF-Program-Guide/Print/Print-Multiple-PDF-Pages-per-Sheet-and-Print-Single-PDF-Page-to-Multiple-Sheets-in-C.html).

However, I need to generate an output PDF, instead of printing it. The

```
   pdf.PrintSettings.SelectMultiPageLayout(1, 2);
```

method only affects printing. When I save the PDF, it still has only one page per sheet.

Has anyone run into this requirement before and found a solution?

Comment: An n-up (like your 4-up) tool should be easy to implement using any general purpose pdf library. I know it's trivial using itext but it should be trivial for other such libraries, too.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your feedback. I've found some n-up online converters, but it's not obvious to me how to do it via .NET. The libraries do seem to have various "drawing" capabilities, but I was looking for something simple, like the example above.